# Actionscript 3 for Android - is there a mobile ready list view control available in Flash Builder 4.5 using Actionscript Mobile project

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I am developing a mobile app in Flash Builder 4.5 based on an Actionscrip Mobile Project - i.e. no flex just pure actionscript.

Is there a listView component that I can use from a pure actionscript project (i.e. a list of items where each item has a picture and some text and you can flick the list up and down with your finger and select an item to proceed to the next screen) ?

After much searching I just don't seem to be able to find one but because it seems like this sort of thing must be available in a platform for developing mobile apps I can only assume I have missed something obvious.  I think there is something like this in a Flex library (?) but I am not sure how to access it or if I even can/should from a pure actionscript project.

(After much searching I sat down and wrote one myself and it seems to work fine and replicates the 'real' thing quite nicely for my purposes.  However I am assuming that someone else will have done it better and so would like to find the real thing if I can).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few AS3 libraries available that you may want to check out:

MadComponents: http://madskool.wordpress.com/ & http://code.google.com/p/mad-components/

I'm testing the MadComponents library right now and it looks promising. Super easy to get up and running. Lacking on the documentation, but I suspect that will change soon as I've been talking with the creator.

AS3Flobile: http://custardbelly.com/blog/category/as3flobile/ & https://github.com/bustardcelly/as3flobile

Looks really nice and I've made a quick test with it. It has another dependency in the AS3 Signals library. Its a bit more involved to get the basic shell of the program up and running and has limited skinning ability from what I gather.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in controls if you are building an actionscript mobile project. You have a large assortment of controls if you build a Flex-based AIR application however.

Comment: So is it possible to access the Flex based AIR controls from actionscript only?

Comment: Yes, but not without incurring the bloatedness of the Flex framework.  So you'd lose the benefit of pure actionscript.  MadComponents are good.